What are the possible ways to Apply rate limiting for my App deployed in Azure Functions App?
I've deployed a Python Backend Application in Azure Function App service.
I need to restrict users to call my API with a rate of 10 requests per minute.
I've tried with azure frontdoor which provides us the possibility of applying rate limit for selected Set of users matched by given conditions, but there is no feasibility to apply rate limit for each client.
Is there any other ways i can apply rate limiting for my APIs ?

Put Azure API Management in front of your Function.

I have created a Http triggered python function for testing purpose and then imported to Azure APIM to apply rate-limit policy.
Thanks @silent for the comment.
You need to import the function as shown below.

Click on Browse and select your function app.

Once the function is imported then you need to use the given policy to limit the number of calls for a specified time period.
Here I am adding the policy in specific operation, you can also add it to API level by clicking on All operations.

Please note renewal period value should be in seconds.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="afreeen-fa" />
        <rate-limit calls="10" renewal-period="60" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>

You will get below response when the number of calls is exceeded.

Trace-

